# How to check if any of value is empty in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to check if ANY value is empty in multidimensional array. I am searching all over the net and find different solutions but not for what i need. Solutions are either for all the values or some specific value or filter out some value and so on.

Thing is that i have a form which can have 2 or 10 input fields, they are repeating with name and surname and package input fields but i can have multiple of them and all of them need to be filled in, so if any field in array is empty i should find it and return error to user so he must fill in all array fields.

```
[povratna_odrasli] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [ime] => 
                [prezime] => 
                [prtljag] => bez
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ime] => 
                [prezime] => 
                [prtljag] => bez
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [ime] => 
                [prezime] => 
                [prtljag] => bez
            )

    )

[povratna_deca] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [ime] => 
                [prezime] => 
                [prtljag] => bez
                [godine] => 0
            )

    )
```

This is basically how array looks when form is submitted

Comment: If you are submiting your input fields via `<form>` you can just put in the `required` parameter, which on the HTML will not allow them to submit the form until they fill in all the required fields.

Comment: can you give an example? are those the only two keys in your array?

Comment: @N.Ivanov this is only frontend validation and can be bypassed by altering the html in the developer console. The best solution would be to use required parameters in input fields AND checking for empty values in PHP like OP asked.

Comment: Yes and i can also use javascript to check before user submit, but if he mess around in developer tools in chrome for example he can remove required parameter and js so he would submit without any restrictions. And yes input is submitted via form.

Comment: This is what you get when you print_r($_POST) @NimeshkaSrimal this is example from input fields from submitted form

Comment: What are povratna_odrasli, povratna_deca and ime, prezime, prtljag ? Do all these keys need to have a value?

Comment: Yes all the keys need to have value, it's basically input from a form, example of one of the field would be: `<input type="text" name="povratna_odrasli[<?php echo $i ?>][ime]" id="povratna_odrasli[<?php echo $i ?>][ime]" class="form-control">` $i represents the key  number in array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `array_walk_recursive` to iterate through the array and it's child arrays like this.

```
$arr=array(
    'povratna_odrasli'  =>  array(
        array('ime' =>  '','prezime'=>'','prtljag'=>'bez'),
        array('ime' =>  '','prezime'=>'','prtljag'=>'baz'),
        array('ime' =>  'knickers','prezime'=>'','prtljag'=>'baz')
    ),
    'povratna_deca'     =>  array(
        array('ime' =>  '', 'prezime'=>'', 'prtljag'=>'bez', 'godine'=>0)
    )
);
$output=array();
$status=array_walk_recursive( $arr, function($v,$k,$o){
    if( empty( $v ) && $v!==0 )$o[$k]=$v;
},&$output );

if( !empty( $output ) )echo '<pre>',print_r($output,true),'</pre>';
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [ime] => 
    [prezime] => 
)
```

If the `$output` var is not empty then you know to process further somehow.

You can find the full description, with example usage for `array_walk_recursive` on the [PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Later versions of PHP throw `"PHP Fatal error:  Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed":` when passing third arg by reference - instead declare the `$output` variable as a global within the callback

```
$status=array_walk_recursive( $arr, function($v,$k){
    global $output;
    if( empty( $v ) && $v!==0 )$output[$k]=$v;
} );
```

Comment: What is: `function($v,$k,$o)` ? ill check out about `array_walk_recursive` more on php page

Comment: That is a callback function - the arguments `$v = $value`, `$k = $key` and `$o = $output`

Comment: you pass a function to array_walk_recursive that is applied to every value recursively. In this function you can then check if that value is empty

Comment: I am getting `Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed` error because i am using php 5.6. There's similar answer to yours on php page but no one explains the error, so googling further.

Comment: ok - I still have 5.3.2 so was unaware there might be an issue. Rather than pass `$output` by reference as the 3rd parameter you could declare it global within the callback function

Comment: You're a legend how fast you edit your answers, i'm just googling for solutions when your edits popup on phone notifications. And this works perfectly fine. Just one question, when $output is not empty it prints array with only one `ime` although i have multiple empty `ime` fields. For me it's not important if i have 1 or 3 empty fields, it's important that it works if any of those fields is empty and it works, just don't know if this is supposed to be like this, or it's kind of bug.

Comment: the output array is only single dimension - you could probably make it multidimensional based upon where in the source array the point happens to be. If you used `$output[$k][]=$v;` you would get to see how many of each field were empty